# AppleScript : can’t set clipboard to

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I know this is probably really stupid
But I can't sent a variable to the clipboard

I still have the error message "can’t set clipboard to "

I try to set the result as a variable and set the variable as text, string, Unicode text, but always the same issue

```
set data1 to "Hello"
set data2 to "Yes"
set data3 to "No"


    set finalResult to "text: " & data1 & "
     Text2: " & data2 & "
     Text3: " & data3 as string

    set clipboard to finalResult
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, AppleScript is not always very smart:

```
set the clipboard to finalResult
```